# Creating multiple buckets with GridFS

Tags: javascript, mongodb, gridfs, multer-gridfs-storage

I am working with the GridFS library in express and node. I'm trying to create multiple buckets. For example I already have a bucket titled avatars, which stores images.

```
    /* Start of mongo connection for uploading files */
const mongoURI = "mongodb://localhost:27017/PTAdata";
const conn = mongoose.createConnection(mongoURI);


let gfs;

conn.once('open', () => {
    gfs = stream(conn.db, mongoose.mongo);
    gfs.collection('avatars');
})

const storage = new GridFs({
    url: "mongodb://localhost:27017/PTAdata",
    file: (req, file) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        crypto.randomBytes(16, (err, buf) => {
        if (err) {
            return reject(err);
        }
        file.user = req.body.username
        const name = file.originalname
        const filename = buf.toString('hex') + path.extname(file.originalname);
        const fileInfo = {
            filename: file.user,
            bucketName: 'avatars'
        };
        resolve(fileInfo);
        });
    });
    }
});
const upload = multer({ storage });
```

I now want to create another bucket called audio which will store mp3 files. I checked the documentation for GridFS at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/ and it states that "you can choose a different bucket name, as well as create multiple buckets in a single database." However it does not provide any insight or steps to how. Has anyone done any work with the GridFS library and know how to create multiple buckets?

Comment: What are you actually importing `GridFs` in your code from? You included tags for both `gridfs-stream` and `multer-gridfs-storage` which are actually two different packages which work differently. You need to specify which you are actually using. FYI, a "bucket" really is nothing more than a "prefix" for a collection name. By default the GridFs spec uses `fs` with `fs.files` and `fs.chunks`, or by named "bucket" i.e `avatars.files` and `avatars.chunks` in your case here. You probably should consider carefully IF you actually want this data in different collections or not.

Comment: It actually appears like you are using [multer-gridfs-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer-gridfs-storage) if you look carefully, there is actually an example on the documentation  page showing the switching of bucket names. It's actually right up the top of the examples. Note also there are other examples there showing you how to share the existing mongoose connection. You just appear to have copied the "crypto" code directly, rather than looking at what all the samples do.

Comment: I am using both packages. I am using the multer-gridfs-storage to actually store the files in the mongo database and I am using the gridfs-stream to stream the files (audio and image) in the browser. I know that a bucket is just a prefix for the two collections created, but what I want to do is create a separate set of .files and. chunks for a different bucket. I am not just trying to change the name of the existing bucket.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store another "new GridFS" object in a different variable, than pass it to multer as a different storage property. In your case, this should work:

```
const storage = new GridFs({
    url: "mongodb://localhost:27017/PTAdata",
    file: (req, file) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        crypto.randomBytes(16, (err, buf) => {
        if (err) {
            return reject(err);
        }
        file.user = req.body.username
        const name = file.originalname
        const filename = buf.toString('hex') + path.extname(file.originalname);
        const fileInfo = {
            filename: file.user,
            bucketName: 'avatars'
        };
        resolve(fileInfo);
        });
    });
    }
});

const anotherStorage = new GridFs({
    url: "mongodb://localhost:27017/PTAdata",
    file: (req, file) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        crypto.randomBytes(16, (err, buf) => {
        if (err) {
            return reject(err);
        }
        file.user = req.body.username
        const name = file.originalname
        const filename = buf.toString('hex') + path.extname(file.originalname);
        const fileInfo = {
            filename: file.user,
            bucketName: 'mp3files'
        };
        resolve(fileInfo);
        });
    });
    }
});

const upload = multer({ storage });

const uploadSongs = multer({ storage: anotherStorage });
```

Finally, you should choose between those buckets accordingly to your endpoints, for example:

```
app.post('/api/uploadAvatar', upload.any(), (req, res)=> {
... do stuff
}

app.post('/api/uploadMp3', uploadSongs.any(), (req, res)=> {
... do stuff
}
```

For me, it made sense to change gfs.collection() in each case (inside the file: (req, file) function), but it worked without changing as well. Be aware that any() is just an option, an it's not the safest one, but it's great for testing your code.